# Convert AnimatedImage to UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to convert an AnimatedImage/ WebImage to an UIImage to get the average color of the UIImage. I imported this library from Github to use the AnimatedImage/ WebImage to load images from any given link: SDWebImageSwiftUI Link: https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImageSwiftUI

That is what my code looks like at the moment -> The error message is that the “cast from AnimatedImage to UIImage always fails”.

```
let i = AnimatedImage(url: URL(string: "image URL")) as! UIImage
```

Is there a solution to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the `AnimatedImage(url:)` method you are using? Is that from some third party framework? You need to include information like that in your question.

Comment: Yes it is an imported library from GitHub. It is called SDWebImageSwiftUI. That provides the function to fetch images from an url: AnimatedImage(url: ).

Comment: You should edit your question to include a link, and also let us know your understanding of how that library is supposed to work, what you think it should be doing, and how it fails to meet your expectations. "of course it fails" is not informative.

Comment: I did update the question

Comment: Ok, you can't cast an `AnimatedImage` to a UIImage. Casting isn't converting. You need to look at the library and see if it exposes still frames from the animation, and fetch one of those.